# GA4 does not recognize the ecommerce 'items' parameter

Tags: e-commerce, google-tag-manager, tagging

To collect e-commerce data, I created a Ga4 data layer with GTM.

value, shipping, tax and items. as below ('item' parameter is just test)

[image]

[image]
But my GA4 doesn't recognize the 'items' parameter ONLY. Look at the picture below
[image]

all of other parameters are doing well, but not 'items'

GA4 does not recognize the ecommerce 'items' parameter.
I can't find a solution.
Do you know why?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? Struggling with it also :/

Answer (score 0):

One way that works for only one item in the items array, is by defining a datalayer variable for each component of the items array.

Example defining a datalayer variable for each component of the items array

Dont forget to check the last parameter configuration on the image. Ecommerce; check Send ecommerce data, and select Datalayer.

Hernan

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are missing the "[]" when you define the variable "items" in the dataLayer.
When this happens, the variable items is recognized as an "object" and you need an "array". You can check this debugging with tag assitant in variables section.
This happens to me many times and you can either correct the data Layer of define a custom java script variables to add the "[]" to the variable.

items: [{ item_id: 'xxxxx', item_name: 'yyyy' , ... ]}

Good luck!
Andrés